# Core Data Queries

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I am still trying to wrap my head around Core Data and am having trouble letting go of SQL. I know that they are not the same but I am finding it hard to recreate what I can do in SQL. I am hoping someone can help.

What I want to do is create a list of Clients and return a sum of their current bill. I have two entities:

Client

- name
- address
- etc

Billing

- Client
- date
- amount
- etc

I have created a one-to-many relationship between the 2 entities and have my NSEntityDescription pointing to Client.

Now what I want to happen in SQL terms is this:

`SELECT *, SUM(amount) as Total FROM Clients INNER JOIN Billing......"`

- Can this be done with one Fetch Request or would I do 2 Requests and then merge them?
- Can I somehow use valueForKey:`@"billing.@sum.amount"`?
- Also could anyone recommend a great Core Data book (or website) for beginners, intermediate level?

Comment: There are no such things as inner joins in Core Data.. but at least they have aggregate functions: http://brianflove.com/2012/09/26/core-data-aggregate-functions/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Core Data get sum of values. Fetched properties vs. propagation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565425/core-data-get-sum-of-values-fetched-properties-vs-propagation)

Comment: I understand that there isn't joins in core data. I looked at the link that you provided and I am still confused. Can't the parent entity retrieve any info from the children and vice versa? Or do i need to create another Fetch Request to get the sum of the client's bill?

Comment: Does the `Client` entity have an inverse relationship that points back to `Billing`? Because if not, it should.

Comment: Yes it does. Does this help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > Can this be done with one Fetch Request or would I do 2 Requests and then merge them?

Yes it can be done with one request. [see here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW6)

```
/*UNTESTED*/
- (NSNumber*) billingSumForClient:(NSManagedObjectID*)clientId
                           context:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    NSNumber* total = nil;
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"Billing"];
    [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
    NSExpression *keyPathExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"amount"];
    NSExpression *sumExpression = [NSExpression expressionForFunction:@"sum:"
                                                            arguments:[NSArray arrayWithObject:keyPathExpression]];
    NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
    [expressionDescription setName:@"total"];
    [expressionDescription setExpression:sumExpression];
    [expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSDateAttributeType];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"client == %@",clientId]];
    [request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObject:expressionDescription]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (&error) {
        // Handle the error.
    } else {
        if ([objects count] > 0) {
            total = [[objects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"total"];
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

> > Can I somehow use valueForKey:@"billing.@sum.amount"?

Yes. [see here(@Daniel link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565425/core-data-get-sum-of-values-fetched-properties-vs-propagation)
This might be faster if all your billings are already faulted into your current context.

Comment: Thank you Dan. I will have to use 2 Requests then. The original one that fetches the Client info to populate my table and then this to supply the total.