# Swift - sorting and reducing an array based on values of a second array

Tags: arrays, swift, reduce, enumerate

I am creating a tableView with NSFetchedResultsController. In each tableViewCell there is an amount and in each section title I want to display the total amounts for each section. For example I have an array of doubles fetched from my core data for the complete table

`array = [50.0, 1000.0, 100.0, 50.0]`

and a second array with the number of objects for each section.

`sum = [2, 1, 1]`

My question is how to enumerate and then reduce the first array through the second so the result for the section totals is the following:

`newArray = [1050.0, 100.0, 50.0]`

Perhaps by using enumerateObjectsUsingBlock?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` handles the grouping of items in sections via its `sectionNameKeyPath` property (a keypath that will be evaluated against each object. Objects that would return the same value for this path, will be grouped in the same section). After doing that, going through each section and generating a sum for its items would be trivial.

Comment: You can try using KVC collections operations like @sum.
see more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7572833/452767

Comment: @SergiySalyuk this looks promising. In my viewDidLoad method I am creating an NSNumber array from my fetched items with `value(forKeyPath: "@sum.."` However I am getting the following error: `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key @sum.`

Comment: @brookeemily You can generate the section titles as soon as table view needs them (for example, using titleForHeaderInSection). So you get all your objects for the given section and then run collection operation on the array, just make sure you are using correct attribute names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on the problem I have found the solution using another technique. In case anyone is interested I only needed to add this to my viewForHeaderInSection method:

```
var totalArray = [Double]()    

for i in 0...self.fetchedItemResultsController.sections![section].numberOfObjects-1 {
    let new = self.fetchedItemResultsController.sections![section].objects![i] as! Item
    totalArray.append(new.amount)
}

let amounts = totalArray.reduce(0, +)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most efficient answer, however, I think it answers what you're asking

```
let array = [50.0, 1000.0, 100.0, 50.0]
let sum = [2, 1, 1]
var newArray = [Double]()

//Ensures that the amount of values you want to check in 'sum' doesn't
//exceed the amount of elements in 'array'
if sum.reduce(0, +) <= array.count {
    let val = sum[i]
    var total = 0.0

    for x in 0..<val {
        if x < array.count {
            total += array[index]
        }
        else {
            break
        }
        index += 1
    }
    newArray.append(total)
}
print(newArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

A slight variant, using slices.

```
let array = [50.0, 1000.0, 100.0, 50.0]
let numberInSections = [2, 1, 1]

var sumOfSections : [Double] = []
for _ in numberInSections { sumOfSections.append(0)}
var firstIndex = 0

for index in 0..<numberInSections.count {
  let lastIndex = firstIndex+numberInSections[index]
  if lastIndex > array.count { break }
  let sliceSum = array[firstIndex..<lastIndex].reduce(0, +)
  sumOfSections[index] = sliceSum
  firstIndex += numberInSections[index]
}
```